# Powershell ISE - how to start new tab by command

Tags: batch-file, powershell-ise

I have few old cmd/batch files that use start command to open new windows

If I am in powershell ISE, I was hoping they would automatically open in new tab, but it doesn't work that way

Is there a simple command I can replace "start" with to simply open new tabs? Just trying to reduce taskbar clutter

Comment: New tabs in what?

Comment: Since `PowerShell` doesn't have a `Start` command, and `cmd.exe` doesn't have a tabbed interface, are you expecting to be able to run batch files in separate tabs of the PowerShell ISE object? You may be able to run `.ps1` files using the `CurrentPowerShellTab` `Files` `Add` method: `$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add('C:\MyPath\MyPScript.ps1')`, but I doubt that's what you're intending to do!

Comment: just trying to reduce taskbar clutter, if new process opens in a new powershell ISE tab, thats best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$psISE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-ise-object-model-hierarchy) automatic variable like in below example.

```
$NewTab=$psISE.PowerShellTabs.Add()
$NewTab.Files='C:\test.ps1'
```